# cpp more efficient method (cmp to for loop) to pick struct-based vector for specific element value

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, filter, struct

can i get some advice on how to pick struct-based vector for specfic element value more efficient? for cpp 11?

below is my demo

```cpp
#include <vector>
struct S
{
    int a=0;
    int b=0;
    int c=0;
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<S> v;
    
    v.push_back(S{1,2,3}); //x = S{1,3,3}; 
    v.push_back(S{1,3,2}); //y = S{1,2,2};
    v.push_back(S{2,2,3}); //z = S{2,2,1};
    v.push_back(S{3,3,2}); //w = S{3,3,3};
    
    std::vector<S> a1,b2,c3; 
    
    //a1 should include x and y, i.e. S{1,3,3} and S{1,2,2}
    //b2 should include y and z, i.e. S{1,2,2} and S{2,2,1}
    //c3 should include x and w, i.e. S{1,3,3} and S{3,3,3}
    

    for (auto i : v) // is there a more efficient way to do this?
    {
        if (i.a==1) a1.push_back(i);
        if (i.b==2) b2.push_back(i);
        if (i.c==3) c3.push_back(i);
    } 
}
```

is there a quicker method to do the `for-loop` logic?
e.g. maybe some function like `a1=pick(v,S.a==1)`

I investigated `find()`, `search_n()` and others possibles in `<algorithm>` but couldn't find a clue, can i get some advice? thx

Comment: For starters, you could do it in just a single loop.

Comment: em~~ my bad, not a delicated example, updated...

Comment: All ideas I could come up with require more lines of code (i.e., less efficient in terms of code size), are not necessarily better readable (i.e., less efficient in terms of developer time), and are not guaranteed to be more efficient in terms of execution time. I'd say what you have is already pretty optimal. ;)

Comment: thanks for comment @j6t, the demo code is just a abstract of my case, which in fact is much more complicated, both in pick critics and struct element, any advice or tips will be grateful

Comment: `for (const auto& i : v)` is more efficient

Comment: pre allocate the `a1,b2,c3` as incrementally adding to them will cause reallocations  slowing down the stuff a lot due to copying the stuff over and over again ...

Answer (score 1):

The benefit is debatable but if you are looking for pure C++11 options, consider `copy_if`

```cpp
    std::copy_if(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(a1),
            [](const S& s) { return s.a == 1;});
    std::copy_if(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(b2),
            [](const S& s) { return s.b == 2;});
    std::copy_if(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(c3),
            [](const S& s) { return s.c == 3;});
```

Yes, it loops over the inputs three times but it also only has to keep track of one vector at a time which may lead to better code generation since the register use and number of code paths within a loop are lower.